# prove or disprove, Fundamental Calculus Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For the function

$$y(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sinh(x-t)f(t)dt$$ then is true or not that
$y''(x)-y'(x)=f(x)$ and $y(x)=y'(x)=0$?

For me is not true because
By Fundamental Theorem
$$y´(x)=\sinh(x-x)f(x)=\sinh(0)f(x)=0$$ then $y(x)=c$ with $c$ a constant.
Then $c=\int_{0}^{x}\sinh(x-t)f(t)dt$ but $y(0)=0=c$. I am doing well all this?

Can you help me or give me any hint please?

Comment: btw it's "disprove". "Disapprove" is a word but it means something different

Comment: You haven't used the fundamental theorem of calculus correctly. Notice the *integrand* is itself "a function of $x$". You need the Leibniz Integral Rule

Comment: @FShrike sorry for the English word. Oh you mean product rule for the function $\sinh(x-t)f(t) right?$

Comment: I want to change the dependence of $x$ in this case, but how can i do that? Thank you

Comment: You need to apply the [general Leibniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), because your integrand and your integral limits are dependant of $x$.

Comment: @Eric oh i see, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @Eric In fact, the use of Leibniz integral rule can easily be avoided by expanding $\sinh(x-t)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net really? wow i will try it as you said, thank you too